# google maps integration with react js hooks, map flickers on update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, geocode, react-google-maps

so i was working on a project and i wanted to integrate google maps, so i downloaded these packages (react geo code and react google maps) i read their documentation and found a piece of code on code sandbox to help me get around with integrating the maps, i refactored the code from class to hooks, but when using class components the map does not flicker when updating location marker but when i updated to hooks it started flickering when i change the location marker, is my code or what i refactored missing anything or is it how state is managed with hooks which makes the flickering unescapable
below is the udpated code and this is the original code (https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-platform-g8mjx?file=/src/LocationSearchModal.js)
and any idea why i have 2 markers?

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  withScriptjs,
  InfoWindow,
  Marker
} from "react-google-maps";
import Geocode from "react-geocode";
import Autocomplete from "react-google-autocomplete";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";

Geocode.setApiKey("googleAPIKEYHERE");
Geocode.enableDebug();

const LocationSearchModal = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    address: "",
    city: "",
    area: "",
    state: "",
    zoom: 15,
    height: 400,
    mapPosition: {
      lat: 55,
      lng: 55
    },
    markerPosition: {
      lat: 55,
      lng: 55
    }
  });

  const getCity = useCallback((addressArray) => {
    let city = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
      if (
        addressArray[i].types[0] &&
        "administrative_area_level_2" === addressArray[i].types[0]
      ) {
        city = addressArray[i].long_name;
        return city;
      }
    }
  }, []);

  const getArea = useCallback((addressArray) => {
    let area = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
      if (addressArray[i].types[0]) {
        for (let j = 0; j < addressArray[i].types.length; j++) {
          if (
            "sublocality_level_1" === addressArray[i].types[j] ||
            "locality" === addressArray[i].types[j]
          ) {
            area = addressArray[i].long_name;
            return area;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, []);

  const getState = useCallback((addressArray) => {
    let state = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
        if (
          addressArray[i].types[0] &&
          "administrative_area_level_1" === addressArray[i].types[0]
        ) {
          state = addressArray[i].long_name;
          return state;
        }
      }
    }
  }, []);

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const onInfoWindowClose = (event) => {};

  const onMarkerDragEnd = useCallback((event) => {
    const newLat = event.latLng.lat(),
      newLng = event.latLng.lng();

    setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      mapPosition: {
        lat: newLat,
        lng: newLng
      },
      markerPosition: {
        lat: newLat,
        lng: newLng
      }
    }));
    Geocode.fromLatLng(newLat, newLng).then(
      (response) => {
        //     const address = response.results[0].formatted_address,
        //       addressArray = response.results[0].address_components,
        //       city = getCity(addressArray),
        //       area = getArea(addressArray),
        //       state = getState(addressArray);
        console.log(response);
        const address = response.results[0].formatted_address;
        let city, state, area;
        for (
          let i = 0;
          i < response.results[0].address_components.length;
          i++
        ) {
          for (
            let j = 0;
            j < response.results[0].address_components[i].types.length;
            j++
          ) {
            switch (response.results[0].address_components[i].types[j]) {
              case "locality":
                city = response.results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
                break;
              case "administrative_area_level_1":
                state = response.results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
                break;
              case "country":
                area = response.results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
                break;
            }
          }
        }
        setState((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          address: address ? address : "",
          area: area ? area : "",
          city: city ? city : "",
          state: state ? state : ""
        }));
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }, []);

  const onPlaceSelected = useCallback(
    (place) => {
      console.log("plc", place);
      const address = place.formatted_address,
        addressArray = place.address_components,
        city = getCity(addressArray),
        area = getArea(addressArray),
        state = getState(addressArray),
        latValue = place.geometry.location.lat(),
        lngValue = place.geometry.location.lng();

      console.log("latvalue", latValue);
      console.log("lngValue", lngValue);

      // Set these values in the state.
      setState((prev) => ({
        address: address ? address : "",
        area: area ? area : "",
        city: city ? city : "",
        state: state ? state : "",
        markerPosition: {
          lat: latValue,
          lng: lngValue
        },
        mapPosition: {
          lat: latValue,
          lng: lngValue
        }
      }));
    },
    [getArea, getCity, getState]
  );

  const AsyncMap = withScriptjs(
    withGoogleMap((props) => {
      console.log(props);
      return (
        <GoogleMap
          defaultZoom={state.zoom}
          defaultCenter={{
            lat: state.markerPosition.lat,
            lng: state.markerPosition.lng
          }}
        >
          {/*Marker*/}
          <Marker
            google={window.google}
            name={"Dolores park"}
            draggable={true}
            onDragEnd={onMarkerDragEnd}
            position={{
              lat: state.markerPosition.lat,
              lng: state.markerPosition.lng
            }}
          />
          <InfoWindow
            onClose={onInfoWindowClose}
            position={{
              lat: state.markerPosition.lat,
              lng: state.markerPosition.lng
            }}
          >
            <div>
              <span style={{ padding: 0, margin: 0 }}>{state.address}</span>
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
          <Marker />

          {/* <MarkerWithLabel
                            position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
                            labelAnchor={new google.maps.Point(0, 0)}
                            labelStyle={{ backgroundColor: "yellow", fontSize: "32px", padding: "16px" }}
                        >
                            <div>Hello There!</div>
                        </MarkerWithLabel> */}

          {/* For Auto complete Search Box */}
          <Autocomplete
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: "40px",
              paddingLeft: "16px",
              marginTop: "2px",
              marginBottom: "2rem"
            }}
            onPlaceSelected={onPlaceSelected}
            types={["(regions)"]}
          />
        </GoogleMap>
      );
    })
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    let _isMounted = true;
    function fetchLocation() {
      try {
        Geocode.fromLatLng(state.mapPosition.lat, state.mapPosition.lng).then(
          (response) => {
            const address = response.results[0].formatted_address,
              addressArray = response.results[0].address_components,
              city = getCity(addressArray),
              state = getState(addressArray),
              area = getArea(addressArray);

            setState((prev) => ({
              ...prev,
              address: address ? address : "",
              city: city ? city : "",
              area: area ? area : ""
            }));
          }
        );
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }
    fetchLocation();
    return () => {
      _isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [getArea, getCity, getState]);

  
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "1rem", margin: "0 auto", maxWidth: 1000 }}>
      <h1>Campus Guide Routes</h1>
      <Card bordered>
        <Card.Text label="City">{state.city}</Card.Text>
        <Card.Text label="Area">{state.area}</Card.Text>
        <Card.Text label="State">{state.state}</Card.Text>
        <Card.Text label="Address">{state.address}</Card.Text>
      </Card>

      <AsyncMap
        googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=googleApiKeyHere&libraries=places"
        loadingElement={<div style={{ width: "100%", height: `100%` }} />}
        containerElement={
          <div style={{ width: "100%", height: state.height }} />
        }
        mapElement={<div style={{ width: "100%", height: `100%` }} />}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default LocationSearchModal;
```

Comment: when it's flickering ? when you close info window ?

Comment: when u change the marker position

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
const AsyncMap = withScriptjs(
        withGoogleMap((props) => {
          return (
            <GoogleMap
              defaultZoom={state.zoom}
              defaultCenter={{
                lat: state.markerPosition.lat,
                lng: state.markerPosition.lng
              }}
             id="map-container"
            >
    .....
```

**add css to map-container**

```
#map-container {
  overflow-anchor:none;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i haven't used ids in react before, do i create a file and import it like so

import styles from "../../../../../src/assets/scss/test.css";

and then use this           id={styles["map-container"]}

and any idea why do i have 2 markers

Comment: make sure css will apply to you code as per your code structure

Comment: i added the css to a css file and imported it but doesnt seem to have any effect

Comment: Hi @Asker how did you manage to solve this? can you please share? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You had 2 markers because you kept `<React.srictMode></React.srictMode>` in `index.js`.